# Why i am getting unexpected values?

Tags: decimal

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  double a = 3.5, b = 2.9, c = 3.5, d = 3.5, e = 3.5;

  double fminA = fmin(fmin(a, b), fmin(c, d)),
         fminT = fmin(fminA, e),
         average = (a+b+c+d+e - fminT)/4;

  cout << "The average is: " << average << endl;

  if(average < 3.5) {
    cout << "3.5 is less than 3.5";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I am getting the average of the 4 highest marks, in this case it is 3.5.

However, the the conditional evaluates true, I suppose it has something to do with double precision.